# Sending TCP Request Data using JSR223 in JMeter

Tags: groovy, jmeter, performance-testing, tcpclient, jsr223

I was using JSR223 Sampler to send TCP Request Data in order to send to the IP. But I am not sure of the built-in functions to do so. I have only been successful to see whether the port is listening or not its code is given below:

```
def sock = new Socket()
def host = "myIPNumber" // change it to your host
def port = myPort // change it to your port
def timeout = 10000 // change it to your timeout (in milliseconds)
sock.setSoTimeout(10000)
sock.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port))
if (sock.isConnected()) {
    log.info('Connection established')
    SampleResult.setSuccessful(true)
}
else {
    log.info('Server is not listening')
    SampleResult.setSuccessful(false)
}
```

Can anyone please guide me how I can send some request data to my TCP IP and save its response in some variable.

Things that I've tried:

I've used TCP Sampler but I'm not getting anything in results tree unless I set some connection time and it gives a 500 error. Same scenario for HTTP Raw Request.

Answer (score 1):

If you wrote this code all you need to add is using [Socket.getOutputStream()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getOutputStream()) for sending the data and  [Socket.getInputStream()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getInputStream()) for receiving it.

If not and you copied and pasted it from somewhere:

To send data:

```
def output = sock.getOutputStream()
def data = "hello".getBytes()
output.write(data)
output.flush()
```

to receive data:

```
def input = sock.getInputStream()
def responseReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input))
def firstLine = sock.readLine()
```

to save it into a JMeter Variable:

```
vars.put('firstLine', firstLine)
```

More information:

- [Lesson: All About Sockets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html)
- [Sending data to a server with Groovy](http://prystash.blogspot.com/2014/06/sending-data-to-server-with-groovy.html)
- [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy)